# Click child in sunburst chart, drilldown into parent element

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a sunburst chart in Highcharts, and I want it so that when you click on a "child" element, it will zoom/drilldown into the parent element.  See picture for a visual explanation.[image]

I am able to hard-code the "Financial" target I want like this:

```
mychart.series[0].data[1]
```

based on my data structure.  And I have seen online that I can use the doDrilldown() function for this purpose, but it simply never works.  I have spent hours on this.

I've also tried to trigger "click" events on the parent element, to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of searching, I did finally find the solution which worked for me!

I had to manually go through the Highcharts' js file for sunburst to eventually find this functionality:

```
chart.series[0].setRootNode(drillId, true, {trigger: 'click'});
```

In my case, the drillId for "Financial" was 'financial'.  Miraculously, this works.

Instead of hard-coding, you can simply get the parent's drillId from a click event like so (set up on the chart series itself):

```
series: [{
    type: 'sunburst',
    data: data,
    events: {
              click: function(event) {
                //console.log(event.point);
                var id = event.point.id;
                var parent = event.point.parent;  // also the drillId
                
                // ... do logic here
                
              }          
            },
     // and so on
```

Comment: Thank you Richard, You saved my a lot of time